# How can I launch the standard Android Contact Picker from inside a library project?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I have a library project which contains some UI widgets. One of these widgets needs to invoke the standard Contact Picker:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, SOME_INTEGER_CONSTANT);
```

I do not have access to the Main running Activity (it is in whatever application using my library) to use startActivityForResult.

Is there a way for me to launch this Intent and get the result back all nice and neat inside my library?

I have tried using Fragments, but to start the Fragment I also have to have access to the Activity.

Comment: Does the calling application have the "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes this isn't a permission issue. It is an implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Android default widgets...Implement a listener which gets invoked on that UI widget when clicked. Libraries should not have any dependencies to outer world unless they are really tight to it.

Comment: Ugh. Continuing from my last comment...

I am inside an onClick listener (or onTouch, whichever - that is irrelevant). The issue is I don't have access to the Activity that the calling application was launched with, so I can't use startActivityForResult.